# Flex: Zipcode validator not working properly

Tags: flash, apache-flex, flex3, flash-builder

I just want to validate Canadian zip code using Flex's ZipCode validator. Here how I am doing it it:

```
<mx:ZipCodeValidator
        id="zipCodeTextInputFieldValidator"
        domain="{ZipCodeValidatorDomainType.CANADA_ONLY}"
        source="{this.zipCodeTextInputField}" 
        property="text" 
        triggerEvent=""
        wrongCAFormatError="The Canadian postal code must be formatted 'A1B 2C3'."
    />
```

Issue it validates for US Zip code as well. If I have given `923 424` as zip code, it throws validation error saying `The ZIP code must be 5 digits or 5+4 digits.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited: in source code ZipCode validator check string lenght:

```
// do an initial check on the length
if ((len < 5 || len > 10) || (len == 8) || 
    (!containsLetters && (len == 6 || len == 7)))
{
    // it's the wrong length for either a US or Canadian zip
    results.push(new ValidationResult(
        true, baseField, "wrongLength",
        validator.wrongLengthError));
    return results;
}
```

Can you use Numeric Validator? How look like zip code in Canada?

Comment: I can use numeric validator too. I wanted to give a try to flex's validator first.

Comment: In Canada mode zipvalidator validates string like pattern 'A1B 2C3' only

Comment: Right! My issue is that when I have given domain as Canada only. Why flex api is validating for US zipcode.

Comment: I think it is bad error label, add `wrongLengthError="The Canadian postal code must be formatted 'A1B 2C3'."` to mx:ZipCodeValidator